# Using webpack ProvidePlugin with Rails 5.1 for a Vue app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, vuejs2

I'm trying to use the [vue-introjs](https://github.com/alex-oleshkevich/vue-introjs) package in a Rails 5.1 app.

I've added the **vue-introjs** and **intro.js** packages through yarn.

I want to make this work using the Rails webpacker gem instead of using workarounds.

The vue-introjs documentation says the following is required in the webpack configuration:

```
// webpack.config.js
{
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            // other modules
            introJs: ['intro.js', 'introJs']
        })
    ]
}
```

The Rails webpack setup doesn't have a **webpack.config.js** file by default, but it does have environment specific files, so I tried adding that config to **/config/webpack/environment.js** but that had no effect.

I then tried to adapt the sample found on [this github issue](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/738) which seems to be attempting a similar thing to what I want, but whilst I could get the page to load without any errors, I still get the error `ReferenceError: introJs is not defined` whenever I try to call `myApp.$intro()`, which should return an instance of the introJs module.

As a temporary measure while I couldn't get that working, I've also tried just putting this at the top of my webpack pack file where the Vue app is created:

```
import introJs from 'intro.js'
import VueIntro from 'vue-introjs'
```

But that still has the same error as above, that `introJs is not defined`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to include the introJs module so the vue wrapper package for it will work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would start with configuring webpacker given what you have installed so far:

```
// config/webpack/environment.js

const webpack = require('webpack');

const {environment} = require('@rails/webpacker');

environment.plugins.append(
  'ProvidePlugin-IntroJS', // arbitrary name
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    introJs: ['intro.js', 'introJs']
  }),
);

module.exports = environment;
```

You'll need to restart your dev server when making changes to the webpack config. I would expect you will still need to `import 'intro.js'` somewhere in your dependency graph.

Comment: After altering my environment.js file with that it worked. `import intro.js` was not required anywhere, just appending the plugin was enough. Worth noting that I also had to update my webpacker gem because it was throwing an error saying `environment.plugins.append is not a function` on the old version.

Comment: @rossta I think I have an almost similar issue with this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57760672/rails-6-with-framework7-using-webpacker). Question - how do I know what values to put in `introJs: ['intro.js', 'introJs']`?

Comment: Haven't verified but I think you'd do something like `Framework7: [''framework7/js/framework7.bundle.min']`... You may have to play with it but it basically should map the var name to the import name.